# Prove that $f(A)$ is an open set and $f^{-1}:f(A)\to A$ is differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, inverse-function-theorem

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ an open set, and $f:A\to \mathbb{R}^n$ a one to one and continuously differentiable function so that $\det f'(x)\ne 0$ for all $x\in A$ Prove that $f(A)$ is an open set and $f^{-1}:f(A)\to A$ is differentiable.

Any idea on how to prove this? I´m totally lost.  (This seems related to the inverse function theorem).

Any help or hint will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The inverse function theorem tells you that for each $x\in A$, there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and an open neighborhood $W$ of $f(x)$ contained in $f(U)$ such that $f^{-1}:W\to U$ is differentiable.  So $f(A)$, being the union of these open neighborhoods $W$ around each point $f(x)\in f(A)$, is open.  Since differentiability is a local property, it also follows that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable as a function from all of $f(A)$ to $A$.

---

The original version of the question left out the assumption that the derivative of $f$ is continuous.  In fact, the result is still true without that hypothesis, and can be proven using more advanced techniques as follows.  The [invariance of domain theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) (typically proved using methods from algebraic topology) states the following:

> Suppose $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is open and $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous injective map.  Then the image $f(A)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and the inverse map $f^{-1}:f(A)\to A$ is continuous.

In particular, this theorem applies to your function $f$, giving you that $f(A)$ is open and $f^{-1}$ is continuous.  To get that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable (and its derivative is the inverse of the derivative of $f$), you can use the same argument as in the proof of the inverse function theorem.

In fact, the result is true even if you drop the assumption that $f$ is injective, as long as you only ask for the conclusion to hold locally (i.e., every $x\in A$ has an open neighborhood $U$ such that $f(U)$ is open, $f|_U:U\to f(U)$ is injective, and $f|_U^{-1}:f(U)\to U$ is differentiable).  This result is even harder, and references to proofs are given in the answers to [this question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75049/does-the-inverse-function-theorem-hold-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps).

Comment: And how can I prove that $f(A)$ is open if I assume that the partials are continuous? Any hints?

Comment: Well, I would consider that part of the statement of the inverse function theorem.  What does your version of the inverse function theorem say?

Comment: For this proof I've tried using that for every $a\in A$, there exists two open sets $U\subset A$  with $a\in U$, and $W\subset f(A)$ so that $f^{-1}:W\to U$ exists and is differentiable. How can I use this to prove the statement?

Comment: I have added something on that to the start of the answer.

Comment: Sorry, it might be trivial but why is $f(A)$ the union of those neighborhoods?

Comment: Every point in $f(A)$ is contained in one of them (because it is $f(x)$ for some $x\in A$).